# Can I configure data source specific "global" hibernate mappings?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-mapping

I know I can specify global mappings in Config.groovy with

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
   ...
}
```

but, in a project with multiple data sources (Grails >= 2.0.3), is it possible to configure "global" mappings that are specific to only a certain data source?

My use-case is that I have different legacy databases with different conventions for representing `boolean` fields (e.g. `BIT` and `CHAR(1)`) and I'd like to be able to map those once each.